# In ASP.NET I Need to update a control, run a task, then update control again

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous, task, async-await

I am quite new to ASP.NET, but have a good understanding of WPF so I hoped this would help, but I guess not.

I want to, as the title says, update a `span.innerHTML` then run a asynchronous task, the update the span again.

I've tried this

```
Status.InnerText = "Connecting..."
Await Task.Run(Sub() Thread.Sleep(5000)) 'simulating a long running process
Status.InnerText = "Connected"
```

but it only updates when the task completes.

I have

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" Async="true" AsyncTimeout="20"
```

in my aspx page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Classic ASP really confuses things, IMO. ASP.NET MVC remains truer to the actual HTTP lifecycle. What actually happens with HTTP is that the client (browser) sends an HTTP request to the server, which then constructs a single HTTP response to send back. In the case of a web page request, that HTTP response includes all the HTML.

So, all the work your handler does on the server side "constructing" the HTML is all done *before* the response is sent. Nothing can be sent to the client until the handler is complete. `Await` will not help you in your situation. (As an aside: `Await` is certainly useful on the server side; it helps with scalability. `Await` will yield the request thread back to the thread pool; it just doesn't yield all the way to the client browser).

A more proper technology to use in your case would be SignalR, which supports persistent connections with two-way communication.

For more information, see my blog post on how [`async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html), or my [recent MSDN article on `async` ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

Comment: Stephen, he's not using Classic ASP, despite the tag.

Comment: @Stephen: are you sure "nothing can be sent until the handler is complete"? How about creating partial responses http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388028/ASP-NET-page-partial-rendering

Comment: @WiktorZychla: It's true that you can flush partial responses, or stream responses. But you can't send an entire HTML page and then change the HTML that was sent.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this is an option for you - depending on "where" you (really) want async, Javascript sounds ideal.

Trivial example:

Given an ASP.Net Form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">        
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Status" />
    </div>
</form>
```

---

with Jquery:

```
$(function () {

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "foo.aspx/HelloWorld",
            data: {} 
        }).done(function (d) {               
            $("#<%:Status.ClientID%>").append("..." + d.d);
        }).fail(function (f) {
            //....
        }).always(function (a) {
            //....
        });
});
```

---

WebForm "code-behind" (for "foo.aspx" above), using WebMethod:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Status.Text = "Initial hello at " + DateTime.Now;
    }

   [WebMethod]
    public static string HelloWorld()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return "And hello again from WebMethod " + DateTime.Now;
    }
```

You should see the text "update" on the browser after 5 seconds, without a refresh/postback:

`Initial hello at 11/22/2014 4:40:55 PM...And hello again from WebMethod 11/22/2014 4:41:00 PM`

Hth...

Comment: [WebMethod isn't recommended for use](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/) anymore. [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is more appropriate.

Comment: @mason Agreed, just scoping it to OP's question...also, the server-side stuff in the above isn't really the "meat"..it could be Web API, WCF, etc..just a "mock" so to speak :)